# how to receive parameter passed from one jsp to another jsp?

Tags: jsp

I have used

```
<a href="Editmail.jsp?email=<%=mail.getemail()%>">Edit</a>
```

to pass "email" parameter to "Editmail.jsp".
And,

```
request.getParameter("email")
```

used to receive parameter on "Editmail.jsp" but it didn't work, why?

Comment: What are you getting in Editmail.jsp?

Comment: Could you specify a bit in detail? Whta are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Basically, a user can store its mail account information and **Editmail.jsp** is a page where user can edit in its already stored information. Now, i have to pass the value of _email_ to identify that to which information user wants to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
 value="<%= request.getParameter('email'); %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%= renderRequest.getAttribute("add") %>
```